# Is an exponential family such with respect to any dominating measure?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, exponential-family

Let $\{P_\vartheta \mid \vartheta \in \Theta\}$ be a family of probability measures on $(\mathbb R^n,\mathfrak B_{\mathbb R^n})$, parametrized by the subset $\Theta$ of $\mathbb R^m$.

Consider the following σ-finite measures:

- $\lambda$, the Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb R^n,\mathfrak B_{\mathbb R^n})$;
- $\mu_A$, the measure on $(\mathbb R^n,\mathfrak B_{\mathbb R^n})$ such that $\mu(B)=|B \cap A|$, where $|\cdot|$ is cardinality and $A$ is any countable subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

Let $\mu$ be either $\lambda$ or $\mu_A$ for some $A$.

If $P_\vartheta \ll \mu$ for every $\vartheta \in \Theta$, we say that $\{P_\vartheta \mid \vartheta \in \Theta\}$ is an exponential family if, for every $\vartheta \in \Theta$, there exists a version $f_\vartheta$ of the density of $P_\vartheta$ w.r.t. $\mu$ such that $$f_\vartheta(x) = c(\vartheta) h(x) \exp\left( \sum_{i=1}^k q_i(\vartheta) t_i(x) \right)$$ for some function $c \colon \Theta \to (0,+\infty)$, Borel function $h \colon \mathbb R^n \to [0,+\infty)$, functions $q_i \colon \Theta \to \mathbb R$, Borel functions $t_i \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$.

If we change the dominating measure, i.e. if we choose another σ-finite measure $\nu$ on $(\mathbb R^n,\mathfrak B_{\mathbb R^n})$ such that $P_\vartheta \ll \nu$ for every $\vartheta \in \Theta$, is it still true that for every $\vartheta \in \Theta$ there exists a version $g_\vartheta$ of the density of $P_\vartheta$ w.r.t. $\nu$ such that $$g_\vartheta(x) = \tilde c(\vartheta) \tilde h(x) \exp\left( \sum_{i=1}^k \tilde q_i(\vartheta) \tilde t_i(x) \right)$$ et cetera?

Comment: If $h(\cdot)$ is everywhere positive, this should hold with only $h$ and $c$ changing.